# Traverse through a JSON file

Tags: python, json

Hi I have a lrage JSON file.I'm reading the data from the JSON file & storing it in a list. I need to extract some element from the JSON file. So I wrote this code

```
l=len(alldata_json)
for i in range(l):
  df_school_us.loc[i,'schoolName']=alldata_json[i].get('schoolName')
  data_address=alldata_json[i].get('addressLocations') 
  df_school_us.loc[i,'Latitude']=data_address[0].get('Location').get('latitude')
  df_school_us.loc[i,'Longitude']=data_address[0].get('Location').get('longitude')
  print("i= ",i)
```

len(alldata_json) is returning 87598 & alldata_json contains my json data.But I'm feeling running for loop with this many number of rows is not an optimized approach. Can you suggest me how to do it without for loop?

Comment: You can read json into a DataFrame using pd.read_json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(alldata_json)
df2 = pd.concat([df.drop('addressLocations', axis=1),
           df['addressLocations'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Extracting countryCode, latitude, and longitude

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'locationType': 'ab',
         'address': {'countryCode': 'IN',
                     'city': 'Mumbai',
                     'zipCode': '5000',
                     'schoolNumber': '2252'},
         'Location': {'latitude': 19.0760,
                      'longitude': 72.8777},
         'names': [{'languageCode': 'IN', 'name': 'DPS'},
                   {'languageCode': 'IN', 'name': 'DPS'}]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.concat([df['address'].apply(pd.Series)['countryCode'],
                 df['Location'].apply(pd.Series)[['latitude', 'longitude']]
```

Comment: Hi Pramote, I'm getting data in this format for one column Hi it's putting latitude & longitude in this form `[{'locationType': 'ab', 'address': {'countryCode': 'IN', 'city': 'Mumbai', 'zipCode': '5000', , 'schoolNumber': '2252'}, 'Location': {'latitude': 19.0760, 'longitude': 72.8777}, 'names': [{'languageCode': 'IN', 'name': 'DPS'}, {'languageCode': 'IN', 'name': 'DPS'}]}]` and I need to store country code,latitude & longitude information. Can you suggest me the steps